# SCSI (SAS) hard disk on SATA port?

Tags: hard-disk, sata, scsi, sas

I have a 72GB (15k RPM) SCSI (SAS) HDD from a server machine that I got from a friend which I want to use in my desktop, mainly as the OS drive, but my desktop has only SATA ports. Some online searching for SCSI-to-SATA adapters (and vice-versa) shows there are some such adapters, but I would like to know if they are actually compatible.

Also, will there be any significant performance degradation? And is using such a setup meaningful/harmful?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really about your question, but I would recommend to invest the money you will pay for this adapter into a new HDD. 15k is real loud and 72 is quiet small -- I assume the HDD is old as well. You won't have fun for a long time.

Comment: @frlan , that is exactly what my first reaction was, adapter cost value didn't return much. Still I thought I should know if such setup is possible and effective.

Comment: Aritra, Hardware Recommendations was created for questions seeking a specific hardware recommendation given a set of definitive requirements. General computing and hardware issues are on topic at [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: I've closed this question because it's more of a general advice-type question, which [are no longer in scope](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/343/do-we-still-want‌​-general-advice-questions/345#345).

Comment: I've used SAS drives connected to a standard SATA connection, namely Xbox 360 drives that were being identified as SAS, no issues on my end.